# Are there published works of Eleazar Rokeach (of Worms) in English?

Tags: jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, mussar-ethics, gematria-numerology

A list from  Wikipedia can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms#Ethical_works) of his ethical and pietistic works.

Known as well by:

- Eleazar of Worms (אלעזר מוורמייזא) (c. 1176–1238)
- Eleazar ben Judah ben Kalonymus
- Eleazar Rokeach (more common today)